# Passing current object to a method, reference or pointer

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a `Track` class with a multimap member that contains `Note` objects. One of the methods of the `Note` class is this:

```
float Note::getValue(){
    float sample = generator->getSample(this); // not working
    return sample;
}
```

`Note` also has a member of `Generator` type and I need to call the `getSample` method of that class, which expects a `Note` as argument. I need to pass the current `Note` object and tried doing so with the keyword `this` but that's not working and giving me the error `Non-const lvalue reference to type 'Note' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Note *'`.

This is what the method definition for `getSample` looks like:

```
virtual float getSample(Note &note);
```

As you can see I'm using a reference because this method is called very very often and I can't afford to copy the object. So my question is: any ideas how I can get this done? Or maybe change my model to something that could work?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I also had tried using `generator->getSample(*this);` but this wasn't working either. I'm getting this error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "typeinfo for Generator", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Synth in Synth.o
  "vtable for Generator", referenced from:
      Generator::Generator(Generator const&) in InstrumentGridViewController.o
      Generator::Generator() in Synth.o
      Generator::Generator(Generator const&) in InstrumentGridViewController.o
      Generator::Generator() in Synth.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is what my `Generator` class looks like (the getSample method is implemented in a subclass):

```
class Generator{
public:
    virtual float getSample(Note &note);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare your `Generator` class as abstract, try this declaration:

```
virtual float getSample(Note &note)=0; 
//this will force all derived classes to implement it
```

But if you dont need it you must implement virtual function in base class anyway:

```
virtual float getSample(Note &note){}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a pointer, your code takes a reference. Try this

```
float sample = generator->getSample(*this);
```

Comment: Well that error means what it says, you haven't defined one of the virtual methods you've declared. Either that or you are building your code incorrectly. In any case `*this` is correct, the other problem is another problem.

Comment: Just noticed Denis Ermolin's answer. He's probably right, you need a pure virtual method. 'getSample method is implemented in a subclass' is not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer in C++, so you'll need

```
float sample = generator->getSample(*this);
```

Comment: @Sled that's a completely different issue. Why didn't you post the error message to start with? Why didn't you post real code? Anyway - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix deals with these errors.

Comment: I thought using `getSample(*this);` was just as wrong (because it wasn't working either) so I only the first way I was getting errors. What do you mean with real code?

Comment: @Sled it means that you said you tried using `*this`, but in the question you use `this`.

Comment: Yea, I had tried both ways and neither were working so I only posted my attempt without the `*` (because I thought both were wrong since they both didn't work). Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Pass reference, not a pointer to getSample(). That is write this way:

```
float Note::getValue(){
    float sample = generator->getSample(*this);
    return sample;
}
```